# Query to obtain value among selected values in a comma separated varchar

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have an SQL table as given below

```
  title                     genre
--------------------|----------------------         
The Dark Knight     |  Action, Crime, Drama
The Godfather       |  Crime,Drama
Inception           |  Sci-Fi
```

How can I write a Select query such that all titles with genre "Crime" will be displayed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should fix your data model!  Storing multiple values in a column is a really, really, really bad idea.

That said, sometimes we are stuck with other people's really, really, really bad decisions.  MySQL has a convenient function `find_in_set()` for this purpose.  But you need comma-separate values with no spaces.  So:

```
select t.*
from t
where find_in_set('Crime', replace(genres, ' ', '')) > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff This did the trick! Really appreciate it
Just curious to know in a similar situation like here where I a movie could have multiple genres is there a better way to store it in a DB  (or do you have a suggested way to go about it )?

Comment: @devz. . . .You should have a table `movieGenres` with one row per movie and per genre.  This is the standard way of representing a many-to-many relationship in SQL.

Comment: Got it ! Appreciate your help